# Why aren't old, abandoned, negatively-voted answers auto-deleted, like the questions are?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-questions, low-quality-posts

The Roomba process eliminates closed, negatively voted, etc. types of questions after weekly, monthly, yearly checks. However, I do not understand why the similar checks are not applied to answers.

For example, if today I google for "Is the t-butyl carbocation more stable than the benzyl carbocation?", I would get this [Chem.SE hit](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74943/is-the-t-butyl-carbocation-more-stable-than-the-benzyl-carbocation/86686#86686). Now, obviously, my query is answered in the accepted answer, as well as the other two answers, but why is the fourth answer left there for me to see? It merits deletion, because it is:

- negatively voted: indicating that it is low quality or clearly wrong
- abandoned: user has not shown effort to improve it, it was last edited four months earlier

You can see a similar case [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26570/how-is-a-free-radical-on-allylic-position-more-stable-than-at-benzylic-position/90559#90559), and in many other questions on many other SE sites.

My question remains the same: why aren't old, abandoned, negatively-voted answers auto-deleted? Clearly they don't add any value to that question, so why not delete them?

(I have tagged this [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) because I am interested in the philosophy behind the decision; however, if multiple users agree on the fact that such answers should be deleted we, may edit this into a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request))

---

Dan made a point that "negative scoring answers are useful as a signal of what’s known wrong." However, consider that negatively voted answers are already greyed out below a vote threshold. So, it's clear that the admins at SE don't want us to read them.

That, and if there's any topic where a concept has a possible pitfall, it should be made clear in the answer, in such a format: "This is a popular pitfall: ... Why people think it's correct:... Here's why it's wrong" so that it adds more value to the question. The current trend is mostly a bad/wrong answer and then discussion/argument in the comments about its incorrectness, which does not help future readers.

Comment: The cliffs notes are that negative scoring answers are *useful* as a signal not only of what’s known to be *right*, but what’s known *wrong*.  The obvious example is real etymologies (upvoted) and common-but-fictional folk etymologies (downvoted: no, dear reader, I know you’ve heard this asserted before, but it’s steaming). This quality of wrong answers doesn’t translate to questions: wrong questions are mostly nonsensical, too broad to add any value, etc. Words that can’t teach anyone anything.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for your comment. Sorry but I disagree, and I have expanded my question to elaborate on that.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll come back and read the update tomorrow, and remove or add comments as needed. I think you’re asking a fine question. I’m just giving you one user’s opinion, which could easily be wrong.

Comment: The fact that an answer is greyed out doesn't mean that the admins don't want us to read it. It just means that its not considered useful in the sense of actually answering the question. If the admins really didn't want us to read it, then it wouldn't be visible.

Comment: I'm speculatively certain its also cause no one thought it would be a problem.

Comment: @JasonBassford Greying out stuff makes it harder to read. If they only wished to convey that the answer is not considered useful, the negative vote count would have been sufficient.

Comment: If you can't emit a VLQ flag, but the question is really very bad, you may flag it for mod attention. Furthermore <-3 answers can be deleted by 3 20k+ users. After the first delete vote, the answer will be visible for them on the 10k+ admin pages. If all of these don't happen, maybe the answer is really not soo bad. It may also happen, that the answer is not bad, but the majority of the community disagrees it, and this is why it is voted deeply down. Pluralism dictates for the sites to show also minority opinions, even if they are downvoted.

Comment: @peterh these are indeed some good points. On science sites like Chemistry, it may make sense to delete the wrong answers (because there can be either a right or a wrong). But on more subjective sites like Politics/Philosophy/etc., many negative votes may also mean that the community disagrees with the view.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I think in this case, the delete votes of 3 20k+ users could solve the problem, if the answer survived the initial period of the VLQ flagging. Unfortunately, there is no review queue for the delete votes, maybe the SE doesn't want to give so much power in the 20k+ hands. There were many initiatives on the MSE to have delete review queues on the site, but it didn't happen until now. The SE doesn't want it. I think the chemistry SE is trustable in this sense, that you won't misuse it, but other sites are not.

Comment: @GaurangTandon There are also "delete voter chatrooms", there 20k+ users give eachother tips, where to vote. They serve essentially as an "unofficial delete review queue". As far I know, the SE dislikes it, but they don't intervene until there is no clear misuse.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I think you could create a "delete voter chatroom" and then advertise it on the meta site.

Comment: @GaurangTandon The search function of the answers is continuously attacked on the meta sites, saying that it is bad, but the truth is in my opinion, exactly the opposite. For example, [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A..-3+created%3A7d..) you can find the answers below -3 posted in the last week. There you can find your targets.

Comment: @peterh Thanks! This was certainly very helpful. I'll see what can be done here.

Comment: @GaurangTandon My pleasure :-) What I see on the Chemistry SE, that you have very few 20k+ users. This may be the reason of the lack of the answer-delete activities.

Comment: @peterh "that you have very few 20k+ users." that is precisely the reason why the thought of Roomba occurred to me in the first place, as I was thinking of ways other than the delete votes to get stuff deleted. On a larger science site like Mathematics, getting wrong answers deleted is not at all a problem, because they have many active users, and a chatroom like CRUDE. However, on a low activity site like Chem.SE, stuff like this is hard :(

Comment: @GaurangTandon I think the important thing is the proportion of the 20k+ users to the answering activity. However, if you have many answers, you will have also many 20k+ users with time. The question is, how long. Until that, I think you could profit from that chatroom.

Comment: @peterh I agree with you. But actually, of all those few 20k+ non-mod accounts you see, more than half of them have been inactive for a certain long time, and the few remaining take little to no part in the close/reopen/delete/etc. activities. (so there's no scope for a dedicated chatroom either) In this proportion, the answering activity is significantly high though. The only option left is custom-mod-flagging for one-click deletion. I'll see if we could reach a consensus on this.

Comment: @GaurangTandon You may also ask the meta to become a beta again (but without losing your nice design). Unfortunately, asking anything on the metas result typically a brutal down chain. But, if the site agrees, the SE may hear the initiative. Being a beta again would mean that all the 2k+ users will be able to vote for delete. And you have around 100 of them, while you have only around 5 non-mod 20k+.

Comment: @peterh I think that'd probably be too much, because we wouldn't want to lose our graduated status :P And these negative answers aren't too big a problem for that. I guess I would just need to convince the mods to allow these custom-mod flags.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Btw, the most likely result of your such meta post will be: "there are not so many bad answers", and your meta post will be voted down to the hell.

Comment: @GaurangTandon That query resulted only two <-3 answers on the last week, two flags / week is absolutely below the tolerance level of the mods. Only make your this query 2 times per week, and be ready for a mass of declined flags. It may be also better if your would regularly check the new answers, which are yet eligible for VLQ flagging, which is probably 1 days. So, visit [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer%20created%3a1d..) every day and flag on need.

Comment: @peterh Sure I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @GaurangTandon [Another important thing what I see](http://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/649165/number-of-open-closed-and-deleted-questions-by-month#graph). You had an exponentially growing activity (user base) until around early 2016. Then the part of the count of the closed/deleted questions suddenly jumped up. Since then, your exponential growth were slowed to a slow linear one. In my opinion, you are over-moderating the site and this expel the incomers. It is very bad strategy :-( You should be *far more* acceptive to the new users...

Comment: @GaurangTandon On February this year you killed 671 questions of the posted 1079... this is why you don't grow! If a site does this, it is clearly psychotic, and shows that the VtC voters went IMHO mad.

Answer (score 6):

In a practical sense - there's many more signals to whether a question is low quality (that it's closed for reasons other than being a dupe, is low-scored and so on) than with answers.

In a sense, I assume it's less of a problem - if a question has *other* good content associated with it, that content floats to the top, and folk can and do flag content for low quality or other issues. (and if it attracts poor quality answers, the answers are gone with it as part of a roomba).

I also suspect that answers that are wrong, but not deleted prove to be useful - we don't delete answers that *attempt* to answer a question for being wrong in many cases, and they serve as what they'd call in the military to be a "Negative Example"

Yanno what would add value to the downvoted answer? A comment going "This doesn't seem right - (quick reason)". The downvotes show that it's wrong, and the other *excellent* answers are what people would see.

There's no real broken window effect either - so there's no clear benefit from deleting this specific instance automatically.

Comment: I think I already considered your point "Yanno what would add value to the downvoted answer? A comment going "This dosen't seem right - (quick reason)"." If we want to tell users that there exist wrong answers, a better way to tell them so should be: "This is a popular pitfall/wrong answer: ... Why people think it's correct:... Here's why it's wrong..." directly in the answer box, instead of making the reader to understand the comments to try figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Also, sorry, but I could not get what you meant to convey by the "broken window" effect in this context.

Comment: There's a theory that places with broken windows have more crime. Likewise - one of the goals of the roomba is to weed out low quality, or at least low interest questions automatically improving the overall quality of content, least in theory

Comment: "In a sense, I assume it's less of a problem" I remember a case where a user used a -5 scored answer that broke its system... I never presume anything anymore